# Langchain query using Pinecone and ParentDocumentRetriever returns no results

Tags: javascript, langchain, pinecone, langchain-js

I am really not understanding how to retrieve the parent documents using Langchain's `ParentDocumentRetriever` when using Pinecone. The following code is working for creating the embeddings and inserting them into Pinecone:

```
const pinecone = new Pinecone();

const pineconeIndex = pinecone.Index(process.env.PINECONE_INDEX);
const docstore = new InMemoryStore();

const vectorstore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(
  new OpenAIEmbeddings(),
  { pineconeIndex }
);

const retriever = new ParentDocumentRetriever({
  vectorstore,
  docstore,
  childSplitter: new HTMLSplitter(),
  parentK: 5,
});

// We must add the parent documents via the retriever's addDocuments method
await retriever.addDocuments(docs);

const retrievedDocs = await retriever.getRelevantDocuments("What is emptiness?");

console.log(retrievedDocs);
```

The `retrievedDocs` contains a few parent documents, as expected.

Now that my index is created, I would like to subsequently perform the same operation, but without the `await retriever.addDocuments(docs)`:

```
const pinecone = new Pinecone();

const pineconeIndex = pinecone.Index(process.env.PINECONE_INDEX);
const docstore = new InMemoryStore();

const vectorstore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(
  new OpenAIEmbeddings(),
  { pineconeIndex }
);

const retriever = new ParentDocumentRetriever({
  vectorstore,
  docstore,
  childSplitter: new HTMLSplitter(),
  parentK: 5,
});

const retrievedDocs = await retriever.getRelevantDocuments("What is emptiness?");

console.log(retrievedDocs);
```

This yields no results. The documentation is really rather unclear on this: am I expected to implement my own document store containing all of the parent documents with their accompanying IDs or something like that? Can I save the `InMemoryStore` to the filesystem, or use the `LocalFileStore`? Does this document store pertain just to the parent documents?

I am not sure how to use `LocalFileStore` since dropping it in as a replacement causes my IDE to become unhappy, because it extends `BaseStore<string, Uint8Array>`, whereas `InMemoryStore` extends `BaseStore<string, T>`.

In summary, how would I use Pinecone as a vector store in combination with `ParentDocumentRetriever`? What document store do I use?

It seems to me that this would be a pretty common use case; where might I find an example?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this document store pertain just to the parent documents?

Yes, while the vector store persists the **child** chunks, the docstore persists the **parent** full docs/chunks.

> how would I use Pinecone as a vector store in combination with ParentDocumentRetriever?

You have to first save your index once, then load it when you want to use it. Maybe using **Faiss** instead of Pinecone would be easier to save using the `vectorstore.save_local("faiss_index")` function (https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/faiss#saving-and-loading). For easy remote persistence of you vector store you could also use Postgres PGVector.

> What document store do I use?

For docstore you can use `LocalFileStore` or you can persist it remotely with an SQL store. I wrote a medium article that show how to use SQL persistence with PGVector if you want to go for this solution for remote persistence you can find those details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77802888/10680282).